# Access inbound property and throw exception using groovy transformer - mule

Tags: exception, groovy, mule

To throw a custom exception from mule flows, I am using:

```
<sub-flow name="throwException">
  <scripting:transformer>
  <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
      throw new mypackage.MyCustomException();
  </scripting:script>
  <scripting:transformer>
</sub-flow>
```

Here, while throwing exception I need to send the value of an inbound property. eg:

```
throw new mypackage.MyCustomException("value of inbound variable");
```

I need to replace the above string with the value of inbound variable. How do I access eventContext/mulemessage/payload/ any scoped variables in this groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
throw new mypackage.MyCustomException(message.getInboundProperty('some_variable_name'));
```

See [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/Scripting+Module) under `Script Context Bindings` for a list of objects available in the script context.